# Python TKInter destroy not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, destroy

I am trying to close a TKInter window with `self.win.destroy`.

The following error is thrown when `bind`ing the event to a button:

```
...
Can't invoke "bind" command: application has been destroyed
During handling the above exception, another exception occured:
...
Can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed
```

How do I bind a "close-window" command to the button?

Comment: It would help if you would also post the relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
button['command'] = root_window.destroy # give it the function
# when the button is pressed the call () is done
```

Do not do this:

```
button.bind('<Button-1>', root_window.destroy()) # () makes the call
```

because

```
root_window.destroy()
```

destroys the window before `button.bind` is called.

This is also wrong: but does not destroy the root window:

```
button.bind('<Button-1>', root_window.destroy)
```

because

- the button can not be triggered with the keyboard
- `root_window.destroy(event)` is called but `root.destroy()` only takes one argument.

This does also work:

```
button.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: root_window.destroy())
```

Comment: You should make it more clear that the problem isn't "bind vs. command" but rather "root_window.destroy() vs. root_window.destroy". Though you are correct that defining a command is highly preferred to setting a binding on a button.